# What is the difference between [minor] and [juvenile-law]?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the main site we have [minor]

> Use this tag for questions related to the law for minors, i.e. persons who have not reached the age of majority (usually 16, 18, or 21 years).

and [juvenile-law], which has no usage guidance.

I am not sure whether there is a useful distinction that could be drawn.  Perhaps juvenile-law should be a synonym, but if not, it should certainly have usage guidance.

(There is also [children], typically for use in family law context, and [child] which is deprecated, so confusion there is unlikely if used properly.  I am doing some work cleaning up [child] at the moment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, the term "juvenile law" is connected with or is an alternative term for the youth *criminal* justice system (e.g. in Canada, the Act covering this area has changed from the *Juvenile Delinquents Act*, to the *Young Offenders Act*, to the *Youth Criminal Justice Act*).

On a quick review, 11 of the 12 questions currently tagged [juvenile-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/juvenile-law) seem to use it in that sense. I agree that usage guidance would be helpful. I've given it a [first draft](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/juvenile-law/info):

> To be used for questions relating to youth criminal justice systems. For questions about minors more broadly, use the tag [minor]; or if it relates to their status as a child in family law, use the tag [children].

"Minor" seems broader to me and could relate to all sorts of age-of-majority distinctions: voting, liquor, consent to treatment, conscription, etc. That's consistent with the current usage guidance.